# Create button with link in Yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii-widgets

I am trying to setup a button with a link to a view. However `yii\bootstrap\Button` does not have a property `url`. I would rather use Yii as supposed to just use flat out php. The code as below would be the ideal situation, but since the `url` option does not exist, is there an other way to fix this using Yii?

```
echo Button::Widget([
    'label' => 'label',
    'options' => ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'],
    'url' => Url::toRoute(['/controller/action']),
]);
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You could simply use [Html::a()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#a()-detail) :

```
<?= Html::a('label', ['/controller/action'], ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) ?>
```

Or create your own version of `Button` class to handle this.

PS: you don't need `Url::toRoute`

Answer (score 5):

you can also pass parameter to url

```
<?= Html::a('Update', ['update', 'id' => $model->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
```

You can also render the html

```
<?= Html::a('<span class="btn-label">Update</span>', ['update', 'id' => $model->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
Html::button("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus' aria-hidden='true'></span>",
                    ['class'=>'kv-action-btn',
                        'onclick'=>"window.location.href = '" . \Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['/create','id'=>$model->id]) . "';",
                        'data-toggle'=>'tooltip',
                        'title'=>Yii::t('app', 'Create New Record'),
                    ]
                )
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want your label name or button to have translations

```
<?= Html::a(Yii::t('app','label'), ['/controller/action'], ['class'=>'pull-right', 'style' => 'padding-right:10px;']) ?>
```

If you want to add an icon for this link

```
 <?= Html::a("<i class=\"fa fa-icon\"></i> ".Yii::t('app','label'), ['/controller/action'], ['class'=>'pull-right', 'style' => 'padding-right:10px;']) ?>
```

if you want to pass parameters

```
 <?= Html::a(Yii::t('app','label'), ['/controller/action', id => $model->id], ['class'=>'pull-right', 'style' => 'padding-right:10px;']) ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

For me works:

```
<?= Html::button('Press me!', ArrayHelper::merge(['value'=>Url::to(['controller/action'])], ['additionalOptions'])); ?>
```

So, use `['value'=> Url::to(),]` instead of `['url' => ...]`